# Cordova > 3.0 CLI -> Gitiignore -> What to add?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, gitignore, command-line-interface

I would like to add into .gitignore file in Cordova app all un-important files.

I added these files and directories:

```
# Android
platforms/android/assets/www
platforms/android/bin/
platforms/android/gen/
platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml

# iOS
platforms/ios/build/
platforms/ios/CordovaLib/build/
platforms/ios/www
platforms/ios/MyPace/config.xml
platforms/ios/.staging

# Emulator logs
platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
```

**Question is:**

Is this O.K, or is something what i should to add into .gitignore ?

Thanks for any advice.